# Use a DOM element as mask

Tags: html, css, mask

Fiddle demonstrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0z6ybe5p/

Is it possible to apply an alpha mask to an element (`<div>` in this example) such that it is cut where another element (`<span>`) is present? I want the background image to be visible in a rectangle surrounding the `<span>` text.

Answer (score 1):

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/OJNvmML)

It's possible, but it requires an indirect solution. By using the `clip-path` property we can display the `#target` as a frame and then center the `<h1>`, however this requires some changes.

---

**First** - We need to make the `<h1>` a *sibling* of `#target` not a children anymore.

```
<body>
  <div id=target></div>
  <h1 id="clipper">CLIP HERE</h1>
</body>
```

**Second** - Add the `clip-path` property to `#frame`. You can play a little with the values to make it good looking and you can even use non-responsive units like `px`. [Here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a link to a really good online editor by Bennett feely.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/400/200');
}

#target {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

#clipper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=target></div>
  <h1 id="clipper">CLIP HERE</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: This example manually cuts out a mask around the span. I need the mask to be exactly the size of the span.

Comment: @thewolf, you can do this by using some math, but there is not really another way with pure CSS https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/OJNvmML?editors=1100